# How to tell what is in one vector and not another?

Tags: r, vector

In matlab there is a way to find the values in one vector but not in the other.

for example:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
y <- c(2,3,4)
```

is there any function that would tell me that the value in `x` that's not in `y` is 1?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

you can use the setdiff() (set difference) function:

```
> setdiff(x, y)
[1] 1
```

Comment: Watchout: `setdiff(x,y)` and `setdiff(y,x)` are not the same.

Answer (score 64):

Yes.  For vectors you can simply use the `%in%` operator or `is.element()` function.

```
> x[!(x %in% y)]
1
```

For a matrix, there are many difference approaches.  `merge()` is probably the most straight forward.  I suggest [looking at this question for that scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right).

Answer (score 32):

The help file in R for [setdiff, union, intersect, setequal, and is.element](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/sets.html) provides information on the standard set functions in R.

`setdiff(x, y)` returns the elements of `x` that are not in `y`.

As noted above, it is an asymmetric difference.
So for example:

```
> x <- c(1,2,3,4)
> y <- c(2,3,4,5)
> 
> setdiff(x, y)
[1] 1
> setdiff(y, x)
[1] 5
> union(setdiff(x, y), setdiff(y, x))
[1] 1 5
```

Answer (score 12):

```
x[is.na(match(x,y))]
```

Answer (score 8):

`setdiff()` is a tricky function because the output is dependent on the order of the input. You can instead write a simple function as such that does the exact opposite of `intersect`. This is far better.

```
>difference <- function(x, y) {
c(setdiff(x, y), setdiff(y, x))
}

#Now lets test it. 
>x <- c(1,2,3,4)
>y <- c(2,3,4,5)

>difference(x,y)
[1] 1 5
```

Answer (score 6):

If:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
y <- c(2,3,4)
```

Any of these expressions:

```
setdiff(x, y)
x[!(x %in% y)]
x[is.na(match(x,y))]
x[!(is.element(x,y))]
```

will give you the right answer `[1] 1`, if the goal is to find the values/characters in `x`, that is not present in `y`.

However, applying the above expressions can be tricky  and can give undesirable results depending on the nature of the vector, and the position of x and y in the expression. For instance, if:

```
x <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4)
y <- c(2,3,4)
```

and the goal is just to find the unique values/characters in `x`, that is not present in `y` or vice-versa. Applying any of these expressions will still give the right answer `[1] 1`:

```
union(setdiff(x, y), setdiff(y, x))
```

Thanks to contribution of [Jeromy Anglim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180892/jeromy-anglim)

OR:

```
difference <- function(x, y) {
c(setdiff(x, y), setdiff(y, x))
}
difference(y,x)
```

Thanks to contribution of [Workhouse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1871399/workhorse)