# How can I get the complement of vector y in vector x

Tags: r, vector

That's `x \ y` using mathematical notation. Suppose

```
x <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,1,1,1,3) 
y <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)
```

How can I get a vector with ALL the values in x that are not in y. i.e the result should be:

```
2,1,1,3
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837968/r-how-to-tell-what-is-in-one-vector-and-not-another). However, none of the answers returns the result that I want.

Comment: You need to define your problem more precisely. Why is 1 in your output even though 1 occurs in y? And then why only two 1s and not three? It would be helpful if you could some kind of pseudocode specifying what you want to compute.

Comment: y is a proper subset of x. And I am looking for its complement in x. I don't care about positions. Had y been c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,1,1,1,3) I should get the rest 4 zeros.

Comment: Y can not be a proper subset of X, because neither of them are sets!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here a solution using `pmatch` (this gives the "complement" as you require):

```
x <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,1,1,1,3)
y <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)
res <- x[is.na(pmatch(x,y))]
```

From `pmatch` documentation:

"If duplicates.ok is FALSE, values of table  once matched are excluded from the search for subsequent matches."

Answer (score 7):

How about this:

```
R> x[x!=y]
[1] 2 1 1 1 3
Warning message:
In x != y : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
R>
```

This is difficult problem, I think, as you are mixing values and positions.  The easier solution relies on one of the 'set' functions in R:

```
R> setdiff(x,y)
[1] 2 3
```

but that uses only values and not position.

The problem with the answer I gave you is the implicit use of recycling and the warning it triggered:  as your `x` is longer than your `y`, the first few values of `y` get reused.  But recycling is considered "clean" on when the longer vector has an integer-multiple length of the length of the shorter vector. But that is not the case here, and hence I am not sure we can solve your problem all that cleanly.

Comment: and setdiff(x, y) is, indeed, the standard definition for x \ y ... since it's a set operation, it first finds unique values and then compares the two vectors.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the problem, you can use `table` to compute the difference in the number of elements in each set and then create a vector based on the difference of those counts (note that this won't necessarily give you the order you gave in your question).

```
> diffs <- table(x) - table(factor(y, levels=levels(factor(x))))
> rep(as.numeric(names(diffs)), ifelse(diffs < 0, 0, diffs))
[1] 1 1 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks, this one is working indeed!. Order does not matter. I am just curious to see how can this be achieved using library `sets` (using a function like `set_complement` perhaps) or another "one liner". I can hardly believe there's no way to get this directly.

Comment: There would be if you were working with true sets. Sets don't have duplicates and order doesn't matter. All the set functions in R are going to follow from that definition... what you actually have is the set X whose elements are {0, 1, 2, 3} and the set Y whose elements are {0, 1}. Thus X \ Y is {2, 3}. While what you're looking for for output is well defined, it's NOT a set operation, so you're going to need to do a little work to get it. You can always wrap Jonathan's code in a function, if you must have a one-line solution.

Comment: If sets don't accept duplicates, there are also multisets that do.