# Getting the excluded elements for each of the combn(n,k) combinations

Tags: r, combinations

Suppose we have generated a matrix `A` where each column contains one of the combinations of `n` elements in groups of `k`. So, its dimensions will be `k,choose(n,k)`. Such a matrix is produced giving the command `combn(n,k)`. What I would like to get is another matrix `B` with dimensions `(n-k),choose(n,k)`, where each column `B[,j]` will contain the excluded `n-k` elements of `A[,j]`.

Here is an example of the way I use tho get table `B`. Do you think it is a safe method to use? Is there another way?

```
n <- 5 ; k <- 3
(A <- combn(n,k))
(B <- combn(n,n-k)[,choose(n,k):1])
```

Another example

```
x<-c(0,1,0,2,0,1) ; k<- 4
(A <- combn(x,k))
(B <- combn(x,length(x)-k)[,choose(length(x),k):1])
```

That [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487922/r-how-can-i-get-the-complement-of-vector-y-in-vector-x) of mine is part of this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using Musa's [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487922/r-how-can-i-get-the-complement-of-vector-y-in-vector-x/2491345#2491345)

```
B <- apply(A,2,function(z) x[is.na(pmatch(x,z))])
```

as regards the first example:

```
B <- apply(A,2,function(z) (1:n)[is.na(pmatch((1:n),z))])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `setdiff` function:

```
N <- 5
m <- 2    
A <- combn(N,m)
B <- apply(A,2,function(S) setdiff(1:N,S))
```

MODIFIED: The above works only when the vectors have unique values. For the second example, we write a replacement for `setdiff` that can handle duplicate values. We use `rle` to count the number of occurence of each element in the two sets, subtract the counts, then invert the RLE:

```
diffdup <- function(x,y){
  rx <- do.call(data.frame,rle(sort(x)))
  ry <- do.call(data.frame,rle(sort(y)))
  m <- merge(rx,ry,by='values',all.x=TRUE)
  m$lengths.y[is.na(m$lengths.y)] <- 0
  rz <- list(values=m$values,lengths=m$lengths.x-m$lengths.y)
  inverse.rle(rz)
}

x<-c(0,1,0,2,0,1) ; k<- 4
A <- combn(x,k)
B <- apply(A,2,function(z) diffdup(x,z))
```

Comment: Thanks. How must be modified in order to work for the 2nd example too?

Comment: Modified to add a solution for the second problem too.

Comment: Instead of this combination you could just reverse gd047 solution: `apply(A,2,function(S) x[setdiff(1:N,S)])` where `N<-length(x)`.

Comment: @marek. Tried it on the original post's second example but it doesn't work (assuming that i got the question right). The elements of S here are the values chosen while 1:N are potential indices. Would it make sense to take their set difference?

Comment: I was thinking about `N<-length(x); m<-k; (A<-combn(N,m)); apply(A,2,function(S) x[setdiff(1:N,S)])`, but disadvantage of this that we don't get `A` with elements of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Here a more general solution (you can replace `X` by any vector containing unique entries):

```
X<-1:n
B<-apply(A,2,function(x,ref) ref[!ref%in%x],ref=X)
B<-do.call(cbind,B)
```

Whereas in your previous question x and y were not sets, provided that the columns of A are proper sets, the above code should work.

Comment: Thank you but in most cases there will be duplicates as was the case in the referenced question.