# Determining different rows between two data sets in R

Tags: r, csv, comparison, rows, import-from-csv

I have two data files in tab separated CSV format. The files are in the following format:

```
EP Code    EP Name    Address    Region    ...
101654    Alpha     York Street    Northwest    ...
103628    Beta    5th Avenue    South    ...
```

EP codes are unique. What I want to do is to compare two files with respect to EP codes, determine the different rows and write them into a new file.

For example, file1.csv has 800 rows and file2.csv has 850 rows. file2 could be a file completely including file1 plus 50 rows; or it could be `file1 - 10 rows + 60 rows`. I want to determine the differences between two data sets. I'm not interested in the mutual rows.

How can I do that in R?

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837968/r-how-to-tell-what-is-in-one-vector-and-not-another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, including `setdiff`, `intersect`, the `%in%` function, `is.element`.  Just find the intersecting set and exclude it using `!`:

```
diff1 <- file1[setdiff(file1$ep.code, file2$ep.code),]
```

or

```
diff2 <- file2[!(intersect(file2$ep.code, file1$ep.code)),]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think there should be an extra right-parenthesis before the last comma in your last code line.