# R - difference between 2 sets in data frame

Tags: r, strsplit, set-difference

I have 2 factor columns, I want to create a third column which tells me what the second one has that the first does not. 
It's very similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162134/comparing-character-vectors-in-r-to-find-unique-and-or-missing-values) but I'm having trouble going from a `df` to using `setdiff()` function.
For example:

```
library(dplyr)
y1 <- c("a.b.","a.","b.c.d.")
y2 <- c("a.b.c.","a.b.","b.c.d.")
df <- data.frame(y1,y2)
```

Column `y1` has `a.b.` and column `y2` has `a.b.c.`. I want a thirds column to return `c.` or just `c`.

```
> df
      y1     y2  col3
1   a.b.  a.b.c.  c.
2     a.    a.b.  b.
3 b.c.d.  b.c.d.
```

I think that is should be a combination of `strsplit` and `setdiff`, but I can't get it to work.

I've tried to convert the `factor` into `character`, then I've tried applying `strsplit()` to the results, but the output seems a but weird to me. It seems to have created a list within a list, which makes it difficult to pass to `setdiff()`

```
#convert factor to character
df <- df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)
lapply(df$y1,function(x)(strsplit(x,split = "[.]")))

> lapply(df$y1,function(x)(strsplit(x,split = "[.]")))
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "a" "b"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "a"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "b" "c" "d"
```

Comment: What about df %>%rowwise()%>% mutate(col3 = gsub(y1,"",y2)). Problem being that if y1 has extra characters y2 does not it won't work. but just an idea of a potentially simpler solution

Comment: Actually this produces correct results. I actually need to to show whats different in y2 that is not in y1. I think all other solutions do the same thing. You can put this as a solution instead of comment.

Comment: One issue with using `df %>%rowwise()%>% mutate(col3 = gsub(y1,"",y2))` is if the order is changed it won't work. Consider if `y1` has `a.b` and `y2` has `b.a.c`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

There was an issue when the difference had more than 1 character, it created an additional row. To overcome that we `paste` all the elements together for each difference. This also saves us from the `unlist` step.

```
df$col3 <- mapply(function(x, y) paste0(setdiff(y, x), collapse = ""),
   strsplit(as.character(df$y1), "\\."), strsplit(as.character(df$y2), "\\."))
```

---

**Original Answer**

We can use `mapply` and split both the columns on "." using `strsplit` and then take the difference between them using `setdiff`.

```
df$col3 <- mapply(function(x, y) setdiff(y, x),
       strsplit(as.character(df$y1), "\\."), strsplit(as.character(df$y2), "\\."))

df
#     y1     y2 col3
#1   a.b. a.b.c.    c
#2     a.   a.b.    b
#3 b.c.d. b.c.d.
```

If we don't want `col3` as list we can `unlist` it however, one issue in that is if we `unlist` it removes the `character(0)` value from it. To retain that value we need to perform an additional check on it. Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659559/unlist-a-column-while-retaining-character0-as-empty-strings-in-r).

```
unlist(lapply(df$col3,function(x) if(identical(x,character(0))) ' ' else x))

#[1] "c" "b" " "
```

Comment: is there any way to convert `col3` into just a normal column? When I run `str(df)` it return `col3` as a `List of 3`

Comment: @jmich738 added in the main answer.

Comment: I'm trying to apply this to my whole dataset but it seems that the output of `col3` produces less rows than the original `df`. I'm still not sure where the problem lies.

Comment: @jmich738 I hope you are doing this in two step. First do the `mapply` step and then do the `unlist` one.

Comment: It seems to be the `unlist()` thats causing the issue. The `unlist` produces extra rows. What I'm doing is saying `df$col3<- unlist(...)`, but on my actual dataset.
 I'm still trying to figure out how my sample data is different from my actual data.

Comment: the problem arises when the difference between the two sets is more than 1 characted. If you change `y2 <- c("a.b.c.d.","a.b.","b.c.d.")` then `unlist()` will create an extra row.

Comment: @jmich738 Apologies, I should have thought about that scenario. Anyway, have updated the answer and it should be fine now. It also reduces one step.

Comment: you are on fire my friend!

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `purrr:map2`:

```
df %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(col3 = map2(strsplit(y2, "\\."), strsplit(y1, "\\."), setdiff))
#      y1     y2 col3
#1   a.b. a.b.c.    c
#2     a.   a.b.    b
#3 b.c.d. b.c.d.
```

Explanation: Convert `factor`s to `character` vectors, use `setdiff` on the `"."`-split columns `y2` and `y1`. Note that `col3` is a `list`.

---

### Update

It appears that `unnest` drops the zero-length `character` entries from the `list`. So to convert `col3` from a `list` to a `character` vector you can do:

```
df %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(col3 = map2(strsplit(y2, "\\."), strsplit(y1, "\\."), setdiff)) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(col3 = paste(col3, collapse = "."))
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#  y1     y2     col3
#  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
#1 a.b.   a.b.c. c
#2 a.     a.b.   b
#3 b.c.d. b.c.d. ""
```

The idea here is to string-concatenate `col3` entries (if there are multiple); using `rowwise()` ensures row-wise `paste`.

For the updated sample data from your comment:

```
y1 <- c("a.b.","a.","b.c.d.")
y2 <- c("a.b.c.e.","a.b.","b.c.d.")
df <- data.frame(y1,y2)
df %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(col3 = map2(strsplit(y2, "\\."), strsplit(y1, "\\."), setdiff)) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(col3 = paste(col3, collapse = "."))
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#  y1     y2       col3
#  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>
#1 a.b.   a.b.c.e. c.e
#2 a.     a.b.     b
#3 b.c.d. b.c.d.   ""
```

Comment: for some reason when I run this I do not get row 3, the one with no differences. Would you know wha that is?

Comment: @jmich738 - the `unnest()` removes any rows which are null in the list apparently.

Comment: @thelatemail ok, so if I run it without `unnest()` I get all the rows

Comment: @jmich738 and @thelatemail You're right! I hadn't realised that `unnest` drops the zero length `character` entries. Please see my updated solution.

Comment: @MauritsEvers very close, but seems that if he difference is more than 1 character, then the results are weird.
 if you set `y2 <- c("a.b.c.e.","a.b.","b.c.d.")`, then the output looks like `c("c", "e")`

Comment: @jmich738 Ah bugger! You're right again. I've made another edit. The key is to ensure row-wise `paste`ing.

Answer (score 3):

A very simple but not rigorous is to replace everything in y1 with "" from y2. 
This won't handle cases where the orders are different or if y1 has anything additional to y2 instead of the other way around.

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(col3 = gsub(y1,"",y2))
```