# R setdiff() by regex

Tags: regex, r

Is it possible to customize `setdiff` using regular expressions to see what is in one vector and not another?  For example:

```
x <- c("1\t119\t120\t1\t119\t120\tABC\tDEF\t0", "2\t558\t559\t2\t558\t559\tGHI\tJKL\t0", "3\t139\t141\t3\t139\t141\tMNO\tPQR\t0", "3\t139\t143\t3\t139\t143\tSTU\tVWX\t0")

[1] "1\t119\t120\t1\t119\t120\tABC\tDEF\t0"
[2] "2\t558\t559\t2\t558\t559\tGHI\tJKL\t0"       
[3] "3\t139\t141\t3\t139\t141\tMNO\tPQR\t0"   
[4] "3\t139\t143\t3\t139\t143\tSTU\tVWX\t0"   

y <- c("1\t119\t120\t1\t109\t120\tABC\tDEF\t0", "2\t558\t559\t2\t548\t559\tGHI\tJKL\t0", "3\t139\t141\t3\t129\t141\tMNO\tPQR\t0", "3\t139\t143\t3\t129\t143\tSTU\tVWX\t0", "4\t157\t158\t4\t147\t158\tXWX\tYTY\t0", "5\t158\t159\t5\t148\t159\tPHP\tWZW\t0")

[1] "1\t119\t120\t1\t109\t120\tABC\tDEF\t0"
[2] "2\t558\t559\t2\t548\t559\tGHI\tJKL\t0"       
[3] "3\t139\t141\t3\t129\t141\tMNO\tPQR\t0"   
[4] "3\t139\t143\t3\t129\t143\tSTU\tVWX\t0"   
[5] "4\t157\t158\t4\t147\t158\tXWX\tYTY\t0"  
[6] "5\t158\t159\t5\t148\t159\tPHP\tWZW\t0"
```

I want to be able to show that:

```
[5] "4\t157\t158\t4\t147\t158\tXWX\tYTY\t0"  
[6] "5\t158\t159\t5\t148\t159\tPHP\tWZW\t0"
```

are new because `4\t157\t158` and `4\t157\t158` are unique to `y`.  This doesn't work:

```
> setdiff(y,x)
[1] "1\t119\t120\t1\t109\t120\tABC\tDEF\t0" "2\t558\t559\t2\t548\t559\tGHI\tJKL\t0"
[3] "3\t139\t141\t3\t129\t141\tMNO\tPQR\t0" "3\t139\t143\t3\t129\t143\tSTU\tVWX\t0"
[5] "4\t157\t158\t4\t147\t158\tXWX\tYTY\t0" "5\t158\t159\t5\t148\t159\tPHP\tWZW\t0"
```

Because column 5 is clearly different in both `x` and `y`.  I want to `setdiff` only based on the first three columns.

A simple example of `setdiff` can be found here: [How to tell what is in one vector and not another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837968/r-how-to-tell-what-is-in-one-vector-and-not-another)

Comment: Is the setdiff supposed to be run as a by row or as a by dataframe test. I'm assuming that the "\t" is an expected separator.

Comment: I believe it should be run as a by row test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to put `x` and `y` as `data.frame`s and anti-join. I'll use `data.table` since I find it more natural.

```
library(data.table)
xDT <- as.data.table(do.call("rbind", strsplit(x, split = "\t")))
yDT <- as.data.table(do.call("rbind", strsplit(y, split = "\t")))
```

Now anti-join (a "`setdiff`" for `data.frame`s/`data.table`s):

```
yDT[!xDT, on = paste0("V", 1:3)]
#    V1  V2  V3 V4  V5  V6  V7  V8 V9
# 1:  4 157 158  4 147 158 XWX YTY  0
# 2:  5 158 159  5 148 159 PHP WZW  0
```

You could also get the row index (thanks to @Frank for the suggested improvement/simplification):

```
> yDT[!xDT, which = TRUE, on = paste0("V", 1:3)]
```

Or extract it directly from `y`:

```
> y[yDT[!xDT, which = TRUE, on = paste0("V", 1:3)]]
# [1] "4\t157\t158\t4\t147\t158\tXWX\tYTY\t0" "5\t158\t159\t5\t148\t159\tPHP\tWZW\t0"
```

Comment: @Frank good call! `which` is one of those `data.table` arguments I've never found a chance to use so it doesn't come to mind. Duly noted.

Answer (score 3):

We could also use `anti_join` from `dplyr` after reading it with either `fread`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
anti_join(fread(paste(y, collapse='\n')), 
        fread(paste(x, collapse='\n')), by = c('V1', 'V2', 'V3'))

#      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9
#    (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (chr) (chr) (int)
# 1     4   157   158     4   147   158   XWX   YTY     0
# 2     5   158   159     5   148   159   PHP   WZW     0
```

---

Or (as the title requests for `regex`) we can use regex to remove part of the string and then do the `%in%`

```
y[!sub('(([^\t]+\t){3}).*', '\\1', y) %in% 
     sub('(([^\t]+\t){3}).*', '\\1', x)]
#[1] "4\t157\t158\t4\t147\t158\tXWX\tYTY\t0" "5\t158\t159\t5\t148\t159\tPHP\tWZW\t0"
```