# Using which and ! functions in R

Tags: r

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")
y <- c("a", "c", "d", "z")
```

I am trying to compare y to x and find an index  where in y that does not match with anything in x. in this case z does match and I want R to return the index of z.

This is one of the things I tried and it does not work.

```
index <- which(y != x)
```

Comment: If you just need the values rather than the indexes, use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837968/how-to-tell-what-is-in-one-vector-and-not-another

Answer (score 3):

use the operator `%in%`

```
 which(!y%in%x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `match` which will return `NA` if there is no match.

```
which(is.na(match(y, x)))
#[1] 4
```

Or another variation with `setdiff`

```
which(y %in% setdiff(y, x))
```