# How to find the indices that were not chosen by sample in R

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, sample

I am using the sample function to extract rows from a dataframe (dat) with 1010 rows. By using:

```
idx <- sample(1:nrow(dat), 707))
```

I extract 707 indices at random. How can I easily get the complement of such indexes? That is, the numbers from 1 to 1010 that were not chosen and are not in idx.

Comment: setdiff(1:1010, idx)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell what is in one vector and not another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837968/how-to-tell-what-is-in-one-vector-and-not-another)

Comment: In practice you can do `dat[-idx, ]` to get the other rows.